# What is the error in my code that once I view all I get the message import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity? link for the error in the picture

Tags: java, android

Main Activity Code, Having an error once I click the view all button, it will show the import androidx.appcompat.aoo.AppCompatActivity. 2 days of debugging still can't see the error.

```
public void viewAll(){
    btView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor res = db.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                showMessage("Error", "No Records Found");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while(res.moveToNext()){
                buffer.append("ID : " + res.getString(0));
                buffer.append("stdnt_id : " + res.getString(1));
                buffer.append("stdnt_name : " + res.getString(2));
                buffer.append("stdnt_prog : " + res.getString(3));

            }

            showMessage("Student Details", buffer.toString());
        }
    });
   }

    public void showMessage (String title, String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();

}
}
```

**Error I get in my alertdialog**

[image: screenshot]

End of Code

Comment: share the logcat , not a picture, and it crashes when you press btView right?

Comment: plz share your layout

Comment: Sorry new in android and in asking a question here in stack overflow, but it shows no errors in my logcat let me put few lines from my logcat since I cannot put the whole logcat. 2020-03-21 12:54:42.595 15507-15512/com.example.sqlitedbapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=58KB, data=61KB
2020-03-21 12:54:42.595 15507-15512/com.example.sqlitedbapp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB

Comment: Abhinav, I'm not having that kind of error yet, but when I press btView the message in the picture shows.

Comment: are you getting App Not Responding Message

Comment: Yes when I tried your the code you give, but during the first code it shows the result that is in the picture and upon checking There is no any red color in my logcat

Comment: It says keeps stopping when I click view all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your misteck is in your  getAllData()
Function, your put value of student detail from edittext perfectly

For example

Std_name.text.tostring()

If you put std_name.tostring() I will show logical error like you have

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 res.moveToFirst();
 while(!res.isAfterLast()){
            buffer.append("ID : " + res.getString(0));
            buffer.append("stdnt_id : " + res.getString(1));
            buffer.append("stdnt_name : " + res.getString(2));
            buffer.append("stdnt_prog : " + res.getString(3));
            res.moveToNext();
}
```

I May be wrong but i think the problem is you never moved the cursor to the first row, and you are just calling `moveToNext()` is a loop so when the cursor is at last row it still tries to go to the next row .

I will also suggest doing the database operations on the background thread , you're doing it on the main thread so as your database will grow i will take more and more time to fetch that data , and your UI will be non-responding in that time and some day you will crash with ANR

Comment: Tried this and when I press btView it crashes already :)

Comment: but thank you guys, I'll be fixing and try to debug it again I think this could be a solution already just a few fixes :) The error in the picture is gone already tho.

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting edittext object to string.

DO this

`String studentName = requireNonNull(studentNameEditText.getText()).toString();`

then  store `studentName` to DB.

Comment: Thank you! :) I'll try this one as well.